Android 13 sending data via Bluetooth
Sending data via outputstream, closes the bluetoothsocket.
The bluetooth connection is stable unless I send data from the Android App, then the bluetoothsocket is closed.
I create a Bluetooth connection like this
protected BluetoothSocket doInBackground(BluetoothDevice... devices){

            String[] permissions = {
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            };

            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity2.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity2.this, permissions, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
                    break; // Ak chcete zastaviť požiadavku po prvej neudelenej povoleni
                }
            }

            if (bluetoothDevice != null) {
                try {
                    bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34fb"));
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); // Pridane z Google
                    inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                    outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                    OutputStreamManager.setOutputStream(outputStream);
                    rxThread.start();
                    rxThread.isRunning = true;
                    return bluetoothSocket;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Zariadenie nie je inicializované.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GetDevBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_connect);
                GetDevBtn.setEnabled(true);
                GetDevBtn.setAlpha(1.0f);
                Status.setText("Odpojené");
                
            }
            return null;

        }

I send the data like this
Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new BluetoothAsyncTask().execute("STOP");
            }
        });

private class BluetoothAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(strings[0].getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.e("Bluetooth", "Chyba pri odosielaní dát cez OutputStream", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

AndroidManifest
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_BLUETOOTH"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.companion_device_setup" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="true" />

I tested it on multiple devices.
Android 7, Android 12 and Android 14 work without problems.
But Android 13 is not working.
I send some data, and within three seconds the bluetoothsocket closes.
Data reception in the application works without problems.
I create an Android App in Android Studio.
I will be grateful for any help ......
I tried asynchronous transfer but that didn't help either
private class BluetoothAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                outputStream.write(strings[0].getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                //Log.e("Bluetooth", "Chyba pri odosielaní dát cez OutputStream", e);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

Or it will be the Tablet on which I test it.
Type: UMIDIGI G1 Tab.

Hello everyone. Problem solved. You need to send data all the time, not just occasionally. I had long breaks in sending data. I only sent data when I needed to.
